# Problema con if statement

Tags: javascript, if

Hola buena ssoy nuevo en esto y no se como hacer para que o dando a enter o dando click en COMENZAR PARTIDA, entre el codigo, funciona el enter pero no el click=>
**if (e.keyCode == 32 || document.getElementById('validarFormularioPartida').onclick) {**

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 32 || document.getElementById('validarFormularioPartida').onclick) {

    let textoErrores = "", paisUsuario;

    // Almacenado valores=>
    with (document) {
      let nombreUsuario = getElementById("campoNombre").value;
      let pwd1 = getElementById("campoPwd1").value;
      let pwd2 = getElementById("campoPwd2").value;
      let emailUsuario = getElementById("campoEmail").value;
      let dniUsuario = getElementById("campoDNI").value;
      let nacimientoUsuario = getElementById("campoFecha").value;
      let radiosPais = getElementsByName('pais');
      for (let i = 0; i < radiosPais.length; i++) {
        if (radiosPais[i].checked) {
          paisUsuario = radiosPais[i].value; // valdra el value del pais usuario
        }
      }

      let pagoIndex = getElementById("listaPago").selectedIndex;
      let pagoTexto = getElementById("listaPago").options[pagoIndex].text;
      let condiciones = getElementById('checkCondiciones').checked;

      // Creación objetos de fecha
      let splitFechaNacimiento = nacimientoUsuario.split("/");
      let objFechaNacimiento = new Date(splitFechaNacimiento[2],splitFechaNacimiento[1]-1,splitFechaNacimiento[0]);

      let objFechaActual = new Date();
      let valorAhnoMinimo = objFechaActual.getFullYear() - 18;
      let objFechaMinima = new Date();
      objFechaMinima.setFullYear(valorAhnoMinimo);


      if(nombreUsuario === null || pwd1 === null || pwd2 === null || emailUsuario === null || dniUsuario === null || nacimientoUsuario === null || pagoIndex === null || condiciones === null){

        alert("Error: no se envió la información");

      }else{
        if (nombreUsuario.length < 5 || nombreUsuario.includes(" ")){
          textoErrores += "El nombre de usuario es de 6 carateres mínimo, sin espacios<br>";
        }
        if (pwd1.length < 7 || !/[a-z]/.test(pwd1) || !/[A-Z]/.test(pwd1) || !/[0-9]/.test(pwd1) ){
          textoErrores += "El campo 'Contraseña' no es correcto. Es obligatorio, de mínimo 7 caracteres, y debe contener una mayúscula, una minúscula y un dígito.<br>";
        }
        if (pwd1 != pwd2){
          textoErrores += "Las contraseñas no coinciden.<br>";
        }
        if (emailUsuario.length === 0 || emailUsuario.indexOf("@") < 1 || emailUsuario.indexOf(".") < 3 ){
          textoErrores += "El formato del email es incorrecto.<br>";
        }
        if (!/^\d{8}[A-Z]$/.test(dniUsuario)) {
          textoErrores += "El formato de DNI debe ser 00000000X.<br>";
        }
        //{1,2} UNO ó  DOS !!!
        if (!/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}$/.test(nacimientoUsuario)) {
          textoErrores += "El formato de fecha debe ser dd/mm/aaaa.<br>";
        }
        if (objFechaNacimiento > objFechaMinima) {
          textoErrores += "Juego reservado a mayores de edad.<br>";
        }
        if (!paisUsuario) {
          textoErrores += "Indica tu país de residencia.<br>";
        }
        if (pagoIndex === 0){
          textoErrores += "Debe seleccionar la forma de pago.<br>";
        }
        if (!condiciones){
          textoErrores += "Debes aceptar las condiciones de uso.<br>";
        }
        if (textoErrores){
          getElementById("errores").innerHTML = "Se han encontrado los siguiente errores:<br><br> " + textoErrores;
        }
        else{
          opener.objPartida.iniciada = true;
          opener.document.getElementById('nombreUsuario').textContent = nombreUsuario;
          opener.msg('success', 'Partida creada correctamente');
          window.close();
          let objFecha = new Date();
          let opcionesFecha = {
            weekday: 'short',
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric',
          };
          let textoFecha = objFecha.toLocaleDateString('es', opcionesFecha)
          opener.document.getElementById('fechaPartida').textContent = textoFecha;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
hr {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-top: none;
}

body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 96vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background: url('../img/back.jpg') no-repeat center / cover;
}

.nuevoEdificio, .actualizarEdificio, .mercado {
    background: white
}

header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/sprite-a.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    height: 87px;
}
header img{
    margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
    width: 200px;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.panel * {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
}

.panel h1 {
  padding-top: 30px
}

.panelPrincipal .controles {
  padding-top: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.panelPrincipal .controles img {
  height: 115px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panelPrincipal .controles section {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: relative;
}
.panelPrincipal .controles section:first-of-type {
  width: auto;
}

.panelPrincipal button, .panel a {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border: medium none;
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 7px 0px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 6px 39px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border: 3px solid #ca6c38;
  color: white;
}

.panelPrincipal button:first-of-type{
  margin-top: 0
}

#contadorEdificios::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('../img/edificios.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: -26px;
  top: -2px;
}

#contadorRecaudacion::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('../img/entradas.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: -26px;
  top: -2px;
}

#contadorVisitantes::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('../img/habitantes.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: -26px;
  top: -2px;
}

#contadorUnidades::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('../img/unidades.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: -26px;
  top: -2px;
}

#contadorSaldoActual {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: -6px;
  background: gold;
  padding: 3px 13px;
  border-radius: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#recaudarCaja {
  background: none;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: rgb(248,248,248);
}

.panelPrincipal section:nth-child(3) img {
  height: 84px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.panelPrincipal section:nth-child(4) p {
  position: relative;
  left: 24px;
}

.mapa {
  width: 900px;
  background: url('../img/mapa.jpg') no-repeat center / contain;
  height: 477px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow:  0 0 1em white
}




.mapa > div {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 20%;
  border-left: 1px dashed transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}


.mapa > div[data-celda] {
  border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-left: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-right: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mapa > div[data-celda]:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3)
}

div[data-celda="01"],div[data-celda="03"],div[data-celda="04"],div[data-celda="05"],div[data-celda="06"] {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed transparent !important
}

div[data-celda="02"],div[data-celda="03"],div[data-celda="06"],div[data-celda="08"],div[data-celda="09"],div[data-celda="10"],div[data-celda="11"]{
  border-right: 1px dashed transparent !important
}

.mapa > div::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mapa > div[data-edificio="vacia"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/vacia.png');
  background-position: center;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="noria"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/noria.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 125%;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="looping"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/looping.png');
  height: 125%;
  background-position: center;
}

.mapa > div[data-edificio="troncos"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/troncos.png');
  height: 125%;
  background-position: center;
}

.mapa > div[data-edificio="rusa"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/rusa.png');
  background-position: center;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: -20%;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="cafe"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/cafe.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 140%;
  width: 140%;
  left: -20%;
  bottom: -20%;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="hamburguesas"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/hamburguesas.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 120%;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  bottom: -6px;
}

.mapa > div[data-edificio="refrescos"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/refrescos.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 140%;
  width: 140%;
  left: -20%;
  bottom: -20%;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="asiatico"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/asiatico.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 140%;
  width: 140%;
  left: -20%;
  bottom: -20%;
}


.mapa > div[data-edificio="auditorio"]::before {
  background-image: url('../img/auditorio.png');
  background-position: center;
  height: 140%;
  width: 140%;
  left: -20%;
  bottom: 0;
}













.panel p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}


button,input[type='submit'],.panel a {
    width:calc(33% - 47px);
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ca6c38 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    border: 3px solid #ca6c38;
    color: white;
}

button:hover,.panel a:hover{
    background-color: #ffccb0;
    color: #ca6c38;
}

.panel button, .panel a, .panel input[type="submit"]{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 12px 0;
    width: 90%;
}

.panel a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

form {
    margin: 24px auto 0;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    font-family: arial;
}

fieldset{
    border: 2px solid #ca6c38;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

legend{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

form label:nth-child(22),form label:nth-child(23),form label:nth-child(24),form label:nth-child(25){
  display: block;
  margin-left: 31%;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="date"], input[type="password"], input[type="number"], input[type="range"], select {
  border: 1px solid #ca6c38;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:first-of-type,input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-left: 27%;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    margin: 0 5px;
}

#errores{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#mensajes,#textoResultado{
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.5);
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.nuevoEdificio figure {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.33% - 40px);
  height: auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 14px 25px 14px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding: 5px;
}

.nuevoEdificio [data-tipo="atraccion"]::before {
  content: "Atracción";
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .5;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.nuevoEdificio [data-tipo="puesto"]::before {
  content: "Puesto";
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .5;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.nuevoEdificio figure:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.nuevoEdificio figcaption {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 !important;
font-weight: 800
}

.nuevoEdificio figcaption span {
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.nuevoEdificio [data-tipo="atraccion"] span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 11px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('../img/habitantes.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: -2px;
}

.nuevoEdificio [data-tipo="puesto"] span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('../img/cash.png') no-repeat center / contain;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
  top: -3px;
}

.nuevoEdificio img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: all .5s;

}

.nuevoEdificio button {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.nuevoEdificio button:first-of-type{
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

#alerta{
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
    padding:20px 0;
}

#alerta[data-tipo="error"]{
    background: #F78181;
}

#alerta[data-tipo="success"]{
    background: #81F79F;
}

#alerta[data-tipo="warning"]{
    background: #D8F781;
}

#alerta.activa{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tú error es que cuando **agregas** un listener como onclick, *debes asociarlo a una función* , y tu lo estas usando como si fuera una variable booleana, osea de `true` o `false`

### Está función hará el trabajo:

```
var add = (e, callback, keycode) => {
     e.addEventListener("click", callback);
     e.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
       var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
           if(key === keycode) callback();
     });
    };
```

### Y la usas cómo:

```js
var add = (e, callback, keycode) => {
 e.addEventListener("click", callback);
 e.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
   var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
       if(key === keycode) callback();
 });
};

add(document.getElementById("Comenzar"), function() {
   console.log("Ha comenzado el juego!");
}, 32);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Comenzar" value="Vamos allá!"/>
```

### Explicación:

- Recibo tres argumentos:

  - El elemento ( e )
  - La función a ejecutar cuando se de click en él o se presione un caracter ( callback )
  - Un caracter , que al presionarlo ejecutará la función pasada. ( keycode )
- Agrego un listener para que cuando se haga click en el elemento, realize la función que pasaste como argumento.
- Agrego un segundo listener, para que cuando se presione cualquier tecla, se ejecute una función. Esta función verificará si la tecla presionada, corresponde a la tecla que pasaste como parámetro ( keycode ), si es así ejecutará la función.

  **La variable key hace lo siguiente:**´

  Si el método which está en el evento ( que denoto con e ) , pues obten el número de caracter con el método which ( e.which)

  Si no, obtengo con e.keyCode()

Para qué? Porque algunos navegadores, llaman a los métodos de diferentes formas aunque tengan la misma funcionalidad.

[Aquí puedes ver los códigos correspondientes a cada caracter](http://keycode.info/)